# function test, [PHPUnit Framework_Exception]: Undefined index: config

Tags: codeception, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to run my functional test and this is the error message i get

[PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] Undefined index: config in C:\wamp\www\test.qsims.com\tests\functional_bootstrap.php on line 4**

I'm trying to parse URL in the functional/_bootstrap.php file. The code for the following is below

```
<?php
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    defined('YII_TEST_ENTRY_URL') or define('YII_TEST_ENTRY_URL', parse_url(\Codeception\Configuration::config()['config']['test_entry_url'], PHP_URL_PATH));
    defined('YII_TEST_ENTRY_FILE') or define('YII_TEST_ENTRY_FILE', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/web/index-test.php');

    // Define our application_env variable as provided by nginx/apache
    if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENV'))
    {
        if (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') != false)
            define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'));
        else 
        define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'dev');
    }
    $env = require(__DIR__ . '/../../config/env.php');
    // comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
    defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', $env['debug']);
    defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', APPLICATION_ENV);
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
    $config = require(__DIR__ . '/../../config/web.php');

    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = YII_TEST_ENTRY_FILE;
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = YII_TEST_ENTRY_URL;
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = parse_url(\Codeception\Configuration::config()['config']['test_entry_url'], PHP_URL_HOST);
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] =  parse_url(\Codeception\Configuration::config()['config']['test_entry_url'], PHP_URL_PORT) ?: '80';

    Yii::setAlias('@tests', dirname(__DIR__));

    (new yii\web\Application($config));
```

When I run my **$ ./vendor/bin/codecept run**. I get the above error.

So the parse_url line i.e. the 4th line is breaking the code. Can anyone help me out in this, trying to solve it from past 6 hrs or so.. Thanks in advance

**Codeception.yml**

```
actor: Tester
#coverage:
#    #c3_url: http://localhost:8080/index-test.php/
#    enabled: true
#    #remote: true
#    #remote_config: '../tests/codeception.yml'
#    white_list:
#        include:
#            - ../models/*
#            - ../controllers/*
#            - ../commands/*
#            - ../mail/*
#    blacklist:
#        include:
#            - ../assets/*
#            - ../config/*
#            - ../runtime/*
#            - ../vendor/*
#            - ../views/*
#            - ../web/*
#            - ../tests/*
paths:
    tests: codeception
    log: codeception/_output
    data: codeception/_data
    helpers: codeception/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    suite_class: \PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
    memory_limit: 1024M
    log: true
    colors: true
config:
    # the entry script URL (with host info) for functional and acceptance tests
    # PLEASE ADJUST IT TO THE ACTUAL ENTRY SCRIPT URL
    test_entry_url: http://localhost:8080/index-test.php
```

**functional.suite.yml**

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
      - Filesystem
      - Yii2
    config:
        Yii2:
            configFile: 'codeception/config/functional.php'
```

Comment: Please add your codeception.yml file to your question, probably config section is missing in it.

Comment: I have added codeception.yml file @Naktibalda

Comment: is it Codeception.yml or codeception.yml ? Codeception only reads codeception.yml

Comment: it is codeception.yml, sorry my bad. Just a type error here, in the code its codeception.yml

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, it works for me.

Comment: Everything seems to be right but I am not sure what is causing this issue. Anyways thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
defined('YII_TEST_ENTRY_URL') or define('YII_TEST_ENTRY_URL', parse_url(\Codeception\Configuration::config()['config']['test_entry_url'], PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Change the above line to the code mentioned below

```
defined('YII_TEST_ENTRY_URL') or define('YII_TEST_ENTRY_URL', 'http://test.qsims.com/web/index-test.php');
```

For some reason it was not retrieving my url form codeception.yml form so I have hardcorded the url in the place of `parse_url(\Codeception\Configuration::config()['config']['test_entry_url'], PHP_URL_PATH))`to actual url :`'http://test.qsims.com/web/index-test.php'`